# joomla package not installing

Tags: joomla, error, installation

I am trying to install the CiviCRM package for Joomla. I have 4.4 and I am installing the latest version of CiviCRM for Joomla. pHp 8.1. Hosting on GoDaddy.

I receive the below error both when uploading from temp (after extracting zip), as well as upload/install of zip. I have scoured the internet but cannot find anyone asking about this/fixing it. Anyone see this before?

[image]

Full code cut off from image:

````
0 Failed opening required '/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' (include_path='.:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/db:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/log:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/mail_mime:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/home/knohnwbd6ym6/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')```
````

Answer (score 1):

So found civicrm.settings.php in a trashed version and was able to copy it over and seems to have gone through. woo!

Comment: Was it a new installation or an upgrade of an existing site?  If upgrade, did you follow the steps at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/joomla/ ?